# jQuery: Only affect elements with a certain class that are children of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery function that toggles a drop-down navigation menu by changing its class on click:

```js
$(function () {
     $('.nav-titles').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropped-down');
     });
});
```

```html
<nav>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
</nav>
```

The problem is that it changes the class of all drop-down menus instead of just the one whose button was clicked. Can I do anything so it only changes the `.nav-dropdown` that is directly under its `.nav-titles` button?

Added the HTML structure as requested.

Comment: Add your **HTML** code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find parent `li` element, and look for the dropdown class on it:

```
$('.nav-titles').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropped-down');
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work:  the thing is that you can't click on the nav-titles class because it wrapped by its li parent, so you must select the li tag for the click & not the nav-titles class, then search for the nav-dropdown class inside of it.

Comment: well the `a` element must have some content or width/height set via CSS to be able to click on them, but i believe they do. you can definitely do it like this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you can't click on the `nav-titles` class because it wrapped by its `li` parent, so you must select the `li` tag for the click & not the `nav-titles` class, then search for the `nav-dropdown` class inside of it.

```
$(function () {
     $('.nav-titles').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropped-down');
     });
});
```

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {

      $(this).find('.nav-dropdown').toggleClass('nav-dropped-down');
});
```

```css
.nav-dropped-down
{
height:20px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a class="nav-titles"></a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
 </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: @opportunityr edited my answer and it works perfectly, the thing is that you can't click on the `nav-titles` class because it wrapped by its `li` parent, so you must select the `li` tag for the click & not the `nav-titles` class, then search for the `nav-dropdown` class inside of it.