# jQuery code is controlling all the block and not the selected one

Tags: jquery

I've this HTML block to control a quantity:

```
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity m-l-5">
        <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
        <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
        <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        $('.qty').val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) + 1 );
    });
    $('.minus').click(function(){
        $('.qty').val(parseInt($('.qty').val()) - 1 );
        if ($('.qty').val() == 0) {
            $('.qty').val(1);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is because I having the HTML at a lot of place, the JS code is controlling all the block whereas it should control the selected one.

How can I change this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Only affect elements with a certain class that are children of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757732/jquery-only-affect-elements-with-a-certain-class-that-are-children-of-another-e)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `this` keyword within the `click` event handlers to reference the clicked button. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the related `input` element, in the example below I use `siblings()`.

In addition, note that you can simplify the condition which ensure that the value cannot be less than one by using `Math.max()`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
  
  $('.plus').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.qty').val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) + 1);
  });
  
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.qty').val((i, v) => Math.max(1, parseInt(v, 10) - 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
  <div class="quantity m-l-5">
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
    <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
  <div class="quantity m-l-5">
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
    <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the event on `.cart-product-quantity>.quantity` block makes sure that the events trigger on right place. Checkout the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setProductQuantityEvents();
});

function setProductQuantityEvents() {
    var $productQuantity = $('.cart-product-quantity>.quantity');
    $productQuantity.find('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
    $productQuantity.on('click', '.plus', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $quantity = $this.siblings('.qty'),
            qty = parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1;
        $quantity.val(qty);
    }).on('click', '.minus', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $quantity = $this.siblings('.qty'),
            qty = parseInt($quantity.val()) - 1;
        $quantity.val(qty < 1 ? 1 : qty);
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity m-l-5">
        <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
        <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
        <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity m-l-5">
        <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
        <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
        <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity m-l-5">
        <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
        <input type="text" class="qty" value="1">
        <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
    </div>
</div>
```